# Google Maps street names not appearing with custom style

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm using the Google Maps API and I have "styled" the maps with this config:

```
    styles: [
                {
                    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                    "stylers": [
                    { "color": "#DACCB1" }
                  ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                    "stylers": [
                    { "color": "#DACCB1" }
                  ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road",
                    "stylers": [
                    { "color": "#EEE3CD" }
                  ]
                },
                {
                 "featureType": "road",
                 "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                 "stylers": [
                    { "color": "#C9B99F" }
                 ]
                },
                {
                 "featureType": "road",
                 "elementType": "labels",
                 "stylers": [
                    { "color": "#000" },
                    { "saturation": "-100" },
                    { "invert_lightness": "true" }
                 ]
            }
        ]
```

The design of the map looks cool, but, after that, the street names don't appear (the unique name that do appear are the places like restaurants, hospitals and others).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"color": "#000"
```

needs to be an RGB hex string:

```
"color": "#FFFFFF" (or "color": "#000000")
```

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1#stylers)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85MMg/1/)